# Why was there a jump in transactions per block in 2023?

Tags: transactions, block, blocksize, transaction-weight, ordinals

[I noticed](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/122290/34190) that there was a jump in the number of transactions per block (from ~2000 to ~3000) in April-May 2023.

The size of the serialised UTXO set also ~doubled from ~5GB to ~10GB over the following year (based on [charts at satoshi.info](https://statoshi.info/d/000000009/unspent-transaction-output-set?orgId=1&from=1553108400000&to=1710979200000)).

What reasons might there be?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The blame is on BRC-20, a terribly inefficient token protocol built on Ordinals that saw a lot of use during that time. BRC-20 requires a huge number of small transactions, which drives down the average transaction size and consequently increases the number of transactions per block.